# check if string exceeds limited characters then show '...'

Tags: php, string, function, conditional-statements, output

I want list some items in the list but upto some few characters, if the characters limit reaches then just show `...`.

I have this `echo(substr($sentence,0,29));` but how put it condition ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`mb_strlen()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php) and an `if`

```
$allowedlimit = 29;
if(mb_strlen($sentence)>$allowedlimit)
{
    echo mb_substr($sentence,0,$allowedlimit)."....";
}
```

or in a simpler way... (*using ternary operator*)

```
$allowedlimit = 29;
echo (mb_strlen($sentence)>$allowedlimit) ? mb_substr($sentence,0,$allowedlimit)."...." : $sentence;
```

in a function:

```
function app_shortString($string, $limit = 32) {
     return (mb_strlen($string)>$limit) ? mb_substr($string,0,$limit)." ..." : $string;
}
```

Comment: Why *mb_* instead of just `strlen`? (You can use [mb overloading](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.overload.php), of course.)

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran So the choice is between `mb_string`, which is an external dependency, or `substr`, which doesn't support multibyte characters, but is built in every default install.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Actually, the manual only says it's unstable in per-directory context. Presumably that means `<Directory>` context in apache configs. It should be as stable as anything else in regular php.ini.

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
if(strlen($sentence) >= 30) {
    echo substr($sentence,0,29)."...";
} else {
    echo $sentence;
}
```

More infos about `strlen()`: http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.strlen.php

Edit/ Crap, wrong function in mind, sry. ._.

Comment: I tested this with text longer than 29 characters and didn't work.

Comment: Scratch that last comment. You forgot the `$` in your `(sentence)` in your original code.

Comment: Well i had a typo in the if, but its fixed now. It works fine on my machine here. Wheres the error?

Comment: @Fred-ii- xD Yes, i thought that this was the error, fixed it already. :D

Answer (score 1):

```
$text = 'this is a long string that is over 28 characters long';

strlen($text) > 28 ? substr($text, 0, 28) .'...' : $text;

gives: this is a long string that i...


$text = 'this is a short string!';

echo strlen($text) > 28 ? substr($text, 0, 28) .'...' : $text;

gives: this is a short string!
```